# How to map REST web service using ServletContainerInitializer?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey

I want to map REST API using `ServletContainerInitializer` and my code is

```
@Override
public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> classes, ServletContext container)
        throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "org.pack");

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(
            "restful", new ServletContainer());
    dispatcher.setInitParameters(map);
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/rest/*");

}
```

The application runs without any error but the webservice is not created. Please suggest where I m wrong and how to use `ServletContainerInitializer` in any web application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand about the `ServletContainerInitializer` is that it's based on the service provider pattern. I went through a tutorial about it a while ago and can't find it now. But you can see some of the requirements in the [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) javadocs. It states:

> A **service provider** is identified by placing a provider-configuration file in the resource directory `META-INF/services`. The file's name is the fully-qualified binary name of the service's type. The file contains a list of fully-qualified binary names of concrete provider classes, one per line.

### Steps I took to get your example to work:

Create a Maven jar project with these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a `META-INF/services` dir. You can put directly in the `src` or with Maven I like to put it `src/main/resources`. They will both end up in the same place.

Create a file named `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` and put the fully qualified name of your `ServletContainerInitializer` implementation in there. Put the file in the `META-INF/services`. Here's mine

```
 META-INF/services/
              javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer

     // content
     jersey.servlet.initializer.MyJerseyContainerInitializer
```

[image]

Here is the initializer class

```
package jersey.servlet.initializer;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class MyJerseyContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> set, ServletContext sc) 
                                                    throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("===============================================");
        System.out.println("                 onStartup()                   ");
        System.out.println("===============================================");
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", 
                   "jersey.servlet.initializer.rest");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = sc.addServlet(
                "restful", new ServletContainer());
        dispatcher.setInitParameters(map);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/rest/*");
    }
}
```

And a simple rest resource class

```
package jersey.servlet.initializer.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/resource")
public class Resource {

    @GET
    public Response getResponse() {
        return Response.ok("ServletContainerInitializer test OK!").build();
    }
}
```

Then I built the jar and installed it to the local repo. Then created another Maven web project, adding the above jar to the project. That's it. Ran it on Tomcat 8 and also 7, and BAM

[image]

---

### That aside

The jersey-serlvet.jar (which is required to use the `ServletContainer` class you are using) already comes with the [`com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server/1.8/com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java#JerseyServletContainerInitializer). Why do we need to create our own?

---

### EDIT

> Its work on maven but i want to do it without maven. Would i have to add project jar into the lib folder for without maven.

Yes, you could build a fat jar for the initializer .jar (including the Jersey jars). Then you would need to place the web project `WEB-INF/lib`. All Maven really does it help with the dependencies and build the .war file. It will also put the initializer jar into the `WEB-INF/lib` of the webapp. So just follow suit, not using Maven. If you don't want to build a fat jar just make sure all the dependencies are included in the lib

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Its work on maven but i want to do it without maven. Would i have to add project jar into the lib folder for without maven.

Comment: Yes, you could build a fat jar for the initializer .jar (including the Jersey jars). Then you would need to place the web project `WEB-INF/lib`. All Maven really does it  help with the dependencies and build the .war file. It will also put the initializer jar into the `WEB-INF/lib` of the webapp. So just follow suit, _not_ using Maven. If you don't want to build a fat jar just make sure all the dependencies are included in the lib

Comment: The `META-INF/services` should go in the `src`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. I was trying to do it last couples of days but didn't get any solution. You helped me lot